# php boolean operation causing 500 error

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter Framework

I am in a controller with the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['field']) && !empty($_POST['field']) && 
isset($_POST['field2']) && !empty($_POST['field2'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['field3']) && !empty($_POST['field3']))
    //whatever
    else
    //whatever
} else {//whatever}
```

the code above throws a 500 error (I am using jquery to send the post data to the page)

```
$.ajax({   
    url: url,   
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data : form,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        checkResults(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
       alert("Fail");
       alert(textStatus);
       alert(xhr);
       alert(error);
    }
});
```

jquery works fine, this is where it gets really weird

the first set of validations (checking field1 and field2) work as intended, however checking field3 gets all screwy

this throws 500 error

```
 if(isset($_POST['field3']) && !empty($_POST['field3']))
```

this doesn't

```
 if(isset($_POST['field3']))
```

this doesn't

```
 if(isset($_POST['field3']) && empty($_POST['field3']))
```

this DOES

```
 if(isset($_POST['field3']) && (empty($_POST['field3']) == 0))
```

this DOES

```
 if(isset($_POST['field3']) && ($_POST['field3'] == ""))
```

I can't figure it out, all the fields have the same format in the view:

```
<input type="text" id="<<ID>>" name="<<NAME>" value="" />
```

The only thing that is different is that field3 is propagated by jquery using a listener

At start it is hided using jquery .hide(), then a simple listener:

```
$("#fieldListener").change(function() {
if(this.value == "") 
{
    $("#field3-id").hide("slow");

    $("#field3").removeClass("required");
    $("#field3").val("");

} else {
    $("#field3-id").show("slow");

    $("#field3").addClass("required");
}
```

Comment: A 500 error means turn up error_reporting and go look in your web server error log.

Comment: _Always_ when developing code, display errors to the screen.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` (they will be visible in your browser inspector, when called from jQuery)

Comment: Somewhere probably in your `//whatever` is likely a syntax error.  Note also that `empty()` implicitly checks `isset()` so you really only need `!empty()` for each of those.

Comment: Try wrapping a little more just for fun -> `if(isset($_POST['field3']) && !(empty($_POST['field3'])))` and stick with the curlybraces for conditions, as it's (in my opinion) good form to be consistent when using curlybraces.

Comment: Written inside the //whatever is where the problem was, I was trying to get the userID of a non-logged in user

Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: Note: `!empty` **implies** `isset` so you can simplify your conditions. `empty` does not raise an error if the variable is not set.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use $_POST with codeigniter.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Read docs if you wan to know more about that :)